# I got the error from node module react-native-cli-platform-android

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\EDLAR\possier\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797    throw err;    ^Error: Cannot find module 'E:\EDLAR\possier\android\undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:
  Run with -- stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

so please tell me how to clear that error

Answer (score 1):

you have uncompleted files in Node_modules

**try**

- Delete the Node_modules folder.
  **then**
- Clear cache.

npm start -- --reset-cache

**LAST STEP** :

- reinstall Node_modules
  npm install

```js
npm start -- --reset-cache
npm install
```

Comment: there is a typo with your `models`. it should be `modules`.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the 'node_modules' folder then,
`npx react-native  --reset-cache`
`npm i`